# the events aren't showing on dates of Calendar initially?

Tags: flutter, dart

**The calendar is working fine,  but the problem is whenever I change the month the events aren't visible on the calendar dates. but it appears after I click on any date. can anyone explain what is going wrong here?**
**Full Calendar Widget implementation**

```
Calendar(
        initialDate: month2,
        startOnMonday: false,
        onMonthChanged: (m) => {
          print("onMonthChanged called: " + m.month.toString()),
          print(month2),
          if (m.month != month2.month)
            {
              setState(() {
                month2 = m;
                year2 = m.year;
                eventsMap();
              }),
              events.clear(),
            }
        },
        selectedColor: Colors.blue,
        todayColor: Colors.red,
        eventColor: Colors.green,
        eventDoneColor: Colors.amber,
        bottomBarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        events: events,
        isExpanded: true,
        dayOfWeekStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12,
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        bottomBarTextStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        hideArrows: false,
        weekDays: const ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
      )
```

**I'm using a calendar widget that displays events on dates in a dot form and also in a form of a list just below it. When I change the month it triggers an onMonthChanged event and fetches the events to display. The only problem I'm having is that Initially, the events aren't showing on dates but after I click on any date, then it shows the events. So, in short, the problem is events aren't displayed initially.**
**onMonthChanged property implementation**

```
onMonthChanged: (m) => {
          print("onMonthChanged called: " + m.month.toString()),
          if (m.month != month2)
            {
              setState(() {
                month2 = m.month;
                year2 = m.year;
                eventsMap();
              }),
              events.clear(),
            }
        },
```

**Calendar class**

```
class Calendar extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<DateTime>? onDateSelected;
  final ValueChanged<DateTime>? onMonthChanged;
  final ValueChanged<bool>? onExpandStateChanged;
  final ValueChanged? onRangeSelected;
  final ValueChanged<CleanCalendarEvent>? onEventSelected;
  final bool isExpandable;
  final DayBuilder? dayBuilder;
  final EventListBuilder? eventListBuilder;
  final bool hideArrows;
  final bool hideTodayIcon;
  final Map<DateTime, List<CleanCalendarEvent>>? events;
  final Color? selectedColor;
  final Color? todayColor;
  final String todayButtonText;
  final Color? eventColor;
  final Color? eventDoneColor;
  final DateTime? initialDate;
  final bool isExpanded;
  final List<String> weekDays;
  final String? locale;
  final bool startOnMonday;
  final bool hideBottomBar;
  final TextStyle? dayOfWeekStyle;
  final TextStyle? bottomBarTextStyle;
  final Color? bottomBarArrowColor;
  final Color? bottomBarColor;
  final String? expandableDateFormat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

provide Date and Time object to

```
initialDate
```

parameter

you are using on month changed callback so you have to use onselecteddate callback

Comment: still not working

Comment: what's actually your problem?define properly

Comment: I'm using a calendar widget that displays events on dates in a dot form and also in a form of a list just below it. When I change the month it triggers an onMonthChanged event and fetches the events to display. The only problem I'm having is that Initially, the events aren't showing on dates but after I click on any date, then it shows the events. So, in short, the problem is events aren't displayed initially.